# Unable to deploy Node.js server on OpenShift

Tags: node.js, express, openshift

Here is my code:

```js
var express = require('express');
var net = require('net');
var app = express();
var sock;


//first of all connect to a stable client
console.log('waiting for connection\nfrom mobile server on port 5132');
var server = net.createServer(function(socket) {
    sock = socket;
});
server.listen(5132);


//receive request from other clients
app.get('/', function(req, res) {
    // retriving mobileNumber and message
    console.log('A new request\nreceived on 6544 ');
    var mobileNumber = req.query.mobileNumber;
    var message = req.query.message;

    if (sock) {
        sock.write(mobileNumber + "\n" + message + "\n");
        res.write(" Wah yyaar...");
    }

    res.end('i am ended');
});

var server_port = process.env.OPENSHIFT_NODEJS_PORT || 8080
var server_ip_address = process.env.OPENSHIFT_NODEJS_IP || '127.0.0.1'

app.listen(server_port, server_ip_address);
```

Here is the error:

```
Git Post-Receive Result: failure
Activation status: failure
Activation failed for the following gears:
56ce93357628e1c35b0000ff (Error activating gear: CLIENT_ERROR:
Failed to execute: 'control start' for
/var/lib/openshift/56ce93357628e1c35b0000ff/nodejs
#<IO:0x00000001d7a388>
#<IO:0x00000001d7a310>
)
Deployment completed with status: failure
```

I think the problem is due to port 5132

But what is the solution?

Answer (score 2):

You are trying to bind to port 5132 on all addresses (0.0.0.0) or the loopback (127.0.0.1) which is not allowed.  You need to use the ip address that you are using for the port 8080 binding, something like:

```
server.listen(5132,process.env.OPENSHIFT_NODEJS_IP);
```